# Rotating the rectangle - OpenGL ES

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, rotation

In a middle of developing my game I created a function to rotate a 2d triangle.
But the problem is that when I rotate an object, the rotation is very weird.
If the object's center is at the origin (the (0,0) point) of the axis then it rotates fine, but if I move the object then it rotates in a very weird way that it shouldn't be rotating in.
as you can see here is the code of the function.

```
public void rotate(float angle){
        float x1 = x, y1 = y;
        float x2 = x + width, y2 = y;
        float x3 = x + width, y3 = y + height;
        float x4 = x, y4 = y + height;

        // Vertices in object space:
        float[] vector1 = {x1, y1, 0f, 1f};
        float[] vector2 = {x2, y2, 0f, 1f};
        float[] vector3 = {x3, y3, 0f, 1f};
        float[] vector4 = {x4, y4, 0f, 1f};

        // Vertices in world space:
        float[] vector1r = new float[4];
        float[] vector2r = new float[4];
        float[] vector3r = new float[4];
        float[] vector4r = new float[4];

        // Calculate the vertices in world space:
        Matrix.multiplyMV(vector1r, 0, modelMatrix, 0, vector1, 0);
        Matrix.multiplyMV(vector2r, 0, modelMatrix, 0, vector2, 0);
        Matrix.multiplyMV(vector3r, 0, modelMatrix, 0, vector3, 0);
        Matrix.multiplyMV(vector4r, 0, modelMatrix, 0, vector4, 0);

        // Get the middle of the rectangle:
        float[] vecMid = {(vector1r[0] + vector3r[0]) / 2,
                          (vector1r[1] + vector3r[1]) / 2, 0f, 1f};

        move(vecMid[0], vecMid[1]); // Move to the origin
        Matrix.rotateM(modelMatrix, 0, angle, 0, 0, 1f); // Rotate the object
        move(-vecMid[0], -vecMid[1]); // Move back to place

        if(LoggerConfig.ON) 
            Log.d("Middle Vertex", vecMid[0] + ", " + vecMid[1]);
}
```

The move method:

```
    public void move(float x, float y){
        Matrix.translateM(modelMatrix, 0, x, y, 0);
    }
```

Can someone tell me what the problem is?

EDIT: I did some modifications to the code and added the move method.

Comment: It sounds like your bug is when you calculate vecMid. Try drawing something to make sure that really is the middle of your triangle.

Comment: Yes it is with vecMid, I checked in the log, the vecMid value gives me different values fro what it should, and I don't understand why.

Comment: nope it's not with the vecMid actually. I check some other variations of code to debug what is going on and from the results I'm sure that it is something with the rotateM function.

Comment: Can you include the code for the `move()` method?

Comment: I added the function and modified the code a little